# 3 level Port forwarding (Kubernetes Pod -> Docker Container -> Local

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, networking, portforwarding

I use a docker container to interact with my kubernetes cluster. I run kubectl from inside the container. All works fine except when I want to port forward. I can use kubectl port forward to forward from the pod to my container. But then I won't be able to access the site from my laptop browser. I can only curl from inside the container.

Is there any way at all I can access the site from my browser. docker host networking mode isn't supported on Macs and I use a Mac. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should `brew install kubectl` so there's one fewer layer involved.

Comment: Yeah, that does work. But the reason I use a container is because we have more than 100 different clusters and we need to ensure everyone is using same version of terraform and a bunch of other things to hit prod in order to maintain version consistencies etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this scenario you may adapt for your need :

On my laptop, I run :

```
docker run -it --rm -p 2222:2222 ubuntu bash
```

From inside container, I run :

```
kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 pod/my-pod-7f66c99ddd-6c429 2222:22
```

Now this is the diagram for port-forwarding :

```
      2222             2222                 2222              22
laptop -------------------> docker-container------------------->k8s-pod
```

Now, in another terminal on my laptop, I can do

```
ssh -p 2222 user-on-pod@laptop-hostname
```

to arrive at pod

Comment: Yup. Just did. It's not letting me accept the answer though as I created my profile just yesterday